# sftp chrooted dosent work with some sftp client (Cyberduck)

Tags: sftp, file-transfer, chroot

I'm not able working on SFTP+chrooted env
Using internal-sftp directive it works, but i'm not able to set umask. (ex umask 002)
Using sftp-server from openssh package dosent't work because login shell for chrooted only user replay with /bin/false (file not found)
This is a sshd server behaviour from:
http://www.openssh.org/faq.html#2.9

My sshd config:

```
Match User sftponly
ChrootDirectory /mnt/www-prod-shared-jail/sftponly/
AllowTCPForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
#ForceCommand internal-sftp -u 002
ForceCommand /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
#ForceCommand /bin/sh -c 'umask 002; /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server'
```

how do you solved this ?
My chrooted environment , in home (chrooted) is /jail/user/bin/false

I try:

- delete .bashrc
- disabled /bin/bash in /etc/passwd setting /bin/false
- try to recreate /bin/bash in choroot but nothing works.

Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks,
Ema

Answer (score 1):

The internal sftp server is running as root and therefore picks up roots umask. you can fix this by forcing the umask e.g. in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` change

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

to

```
Subsystem sftp /bin/sh -c 'umask 0002; /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server'
```

or whatever umask you want.

Comment: I've tried this but it dosen't work.
I think sshd replay to login with some error, like "bin/bahs not found" and login fails

Comment: emaaaa-s-mbp:~ emaaaa$ ssh myuser@myserver /usr/bin/true

 myuser@myserver's password:

 /bin/false: No such file or directory

Comment: Try again with ' as a quote and not `

Comment: `ssh myuser@myserver /usr/bin/true
myuser@myserver's password:
/bin/false: No such file or directory` @lain

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this recently.  Specifying the umask in sshd_config works with sftp, but not with internal-sftp.  Unfortunately, in order to jail the users without creating an entire chroot environment, you have to use internal-sftp.  The good news is that there is still a way to set the umask if you're using PAM.

Create a group that contains all of your sftp users.  For the example, let's call it sftpjail.

Then add the following to /etc/pam.d/login

```
session optional pam_umask.so sftpjail umask=0002
```

This will set the umask for all the users in the sftpjail group.

*EDIT*
If you want to use the config that you have above, I'm pretty sure what you're missing is the chroot environment (binaries, config files, etc.) - hence the "file not found" errors when it tries to chroot.  Though if it were me, I'd go back to using "ForceCommand internal-sftp" and set the umask in PAM

Comment: Hi @Bill B I try this config on my server but It dosent' works.

Comment: @emaaaa  It's working for me on several systems.  My best guess is that you still have something misconfigured.

Comment: I am currently using ForceCommand internal-sftp. So how do I set the umask in PAM? Is that the method you posted? If so, I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @Doug - Yes, adding the above line to /etc/pam.d/login should enforce the umask of 0002 for all members of group sftpjail.  Of course, your group name will be different.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem, but I was using ssh on the client machine instead of sftp. As soon as I used sftp user@host instead of ssh user@host, it worked fine.